# Alternative to dec2hex in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, hex, decimal

I am using `dec2hex` up to 100 times in MATLAB. Because of this, the speed of code decreases. for one point I am using `dec2hex` 100 times. It will take 1 minute or more than it. I have do the same for 5000 points. But because of `dec2hex` it will take hours of time to run. So how can I do hexadecimal to decimal conversion optimally? Is there any other alternative that can be used instead of `dec2hex`?

As example:

```
%%Data[1..256]: can be any data from 
for i=1:1:256
Table=dec2hex(Data);
%%Some permutation applied on Data
end;
```

Here I am using `dec2hex` more than 100 times for one point. And I have to use it for 5000 points.

Data =

```
 Columns 1 through 16

 105   232    98   250   234   216    98   199   172   226   250   215   188    11    52   174

 Columns 17 through 32

 111   181    71   254   133   171    94    91   194   136   249   168   177   202   109   187

 Columns 33 through 48

  232   249   191    60   230    67   183   122   164   163    91    24   145   124   200   142
```

This kind of data My code will use.

Comment: How large are your numbers that you want to convert? What is your version of MATLAB?

Comment: I am editing the code to show examples.Version is R2014b

Comment: Have you tried passing the values you want to convert all at once using a vector? `dec2hex(1:100000)` is quite quick!

Comment: Try `dec2hex(1:1:256)`?

Comment: Converting 500,000 numbers to hex (in parallel) does take `0.22` seconds on my machine, so this is unlikely the reason your computation will take hours.

Comment: This only works for if I have data like 1,2....256. But I think It will not work for different kind of data.

Comment: @SNC: Well tell us what your data is then! How would we know?

Comment: are you sure the problem is `dec2hex`... I ask because in the example  `Data` is not [preallocated](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/techniques-for-improving-performance.html#f8-793781). I would assume that to be the cause

Comment: Your question/problem is poorly defined: "_Here I am using dec2hex more than 100 times for one point. And I have to use it for 5000 times._" Nothing in your example indicates that (Do you really have to call the function 100 times for each data point? Then repeat for 5000 data points? either I misunderstand or it is loosely implemented). As RTL hinted, there is a good chance that the slowdown is in your code organisation, not in the `dec2hex` function alone.

Comment: I preallocated Data but then even It is taking so much time. From matlab profiler I got to know that which function is taking so much time. So In that dec2hex is taking so much time such as 134.6666 s which is near by 1.5 or 2 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function calls are (still) expensive in MATLAB. This is one of the reasons why vectorization and pseudo-vectorization is strongly recommended: processing an entire array of `N` values in one function call is way better than calling the processing function `N` times for each element, thus saving the `N-1` supplemental calls overhead.

So, what you can do? Here are some non-mutually-exclusive choices:

1. *Profile your code first.* Just because something looks like the main culprit for execution time disasters, it isn't necessarily it. Type `profview` in your command window, chose the script that you want to run, and see where are the hotspots of your code. Choose to optimize those hotspots rather than your initial guesses.
2. *Try faster functions.* `sprintf` is usually fast and flexible:

   ```
   Table = sprintf('%04X\n', Data);
   ```

   (and — if you dive into the function code with `edit dec2hex` — you'll see that in some cases `dec2hex` actually calls `sprintf`).
3. *Reduce the number of function calls.* Suppose you have to build the table for the 100 datasets of different lengths, that are stored in a cell array:

   ```
   DataSet = cell(1,100);
   for k = 1:100
           DataSet{k} = fix(1000*rand(k,1));
   end;
   ```

   The idea is to assemble all the numbers in a single array that you convert at once:

   ```
   Table = dec2hex(vertcat(DataSet{:}));
   ```

   Mind you, this is done at the expense of using supplemental memory for assembling the partial inputs in a single one — it's not always convenient to do that.
4. *All the variants above.* Okay, this point is not actually a point. :-)